# Android add a view to fragment and animate the view

Tags: android, layout-inflater

Hi have a button that when you press it a view with two buttons slides up from the bottom. does any know how to do this?

i have tried inflating a view and animating it but it animates the whole view and doesn't show the view i inflated

```
  Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {


                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    View ImageSel = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_image_selector, vg_container);


                    Animation AniMoveUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.tut_image);  
                    ImageSel.startAnimation(AniMoveUp); 
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    //                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                }
            });
```

Comment: show your tut_image.xml code?

Comment: You are trying to animate vg_container. inflate() methods returns root if it is supplied.

Comment: @loop i changed vg_container to null and it doesnt load anything, what should i do iterms of viewGroup

Comment: Call inflate(R.layout.layout_image_selector, vg_container, false) to get object you need. Then add explicitly this view to vg_container. If you don't have a reference to that root, get it earlier with findViewById() method. To be honest I am not sure if animation will work after adding view to the layout. I am just solving your issue with getting the right view reference. You may need to start animation through post() method of your view, letting properly display the view first.